# Socket.io with YARP

Tags: socket.io, ms-yarp

I am trying to build a system using Socket.io and YARP. Yarp is functioning has a Reverse Proxy to all my Services.

When trying establish a connection to my socket.io service, through yarp, I am getting connection_error:
[image: Firecamp screenshot]

I noticed there are proper configurations used in other Reversed Proxy solutions that are well documented in Socket.io website:
https://socket.io/docs/v4/reverse-proxy/

However, I can't "translate" what they are doing to YARP. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess stackoverflow was my rubberduck this time...

I checked in postman the request that was being made through my Yarp Server and turns out it wasn't even hitting the correct path. For yarp to connect to a socket.io server you have to use this kind of path in your configuration file:
[image: socketio yarp config]
It seems that a sokcetio request uses it's own path, so you have to make your reverse proxy match the beggining "socket.io/"